# Generalisation of $A^{k}$ matrix

Tags: matrices, alternative-proof

> Question: If a $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ be
>
> $A=\begin{align} \begin{bmatrix}
>     0       & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
>     0       & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
>     \vdots & \vdots &\vdots &&\vdots& \vdots\\
>      0       & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 \\
>     1       & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0
> \end{bmatrix} \end{align}$
>
> Show that $A^{k}=\begin{bmatrix} O & I_{n-k}\\I_{k} & O\end{bmatrix}$, where $k=1, 2, \cdots, n$.

My attempt is to prove with mathematical induction, but it doesn't work as $I_{k}$ will expand its row and column from $1$ to $n$, leads the multiplication of partition matrices will not hold true.

I know this is a partition matrix with two zero matrices on the first row and column, while another two identity matrices on the sub-diagonals , and what I conclude for the proof is: multiply one-by-one, but the proof will not that strict and does not meet the expectation for generalisation.

Comment: I can't quite follow why induction does not work: induction seems to be the obvious, I would almost say "infallible" approach here.

Comment: Look at this matrix as a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^n$ to itself under the standard basis. By understanding which basis element goes to which basis element under $A$, an induction pattern will instantly tell you what $A^k$ does, and therefore how its matrix looks.

Comment: Hint: this is a permutation matrix.

Comment: So it's the properties of circulant matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $e_1,\dots, e_n$ be the standard basis. Then for any matrix $M$ (with $n$ columns), we have $Me_i$ is the $i$th column of $M$. 
So that, $Ae_i=e_{i-1}$ with cyclic indexing.

> $A^2e_i=Ae_{i-1}=e_{i-2}$, and so on..